# Assign daily data to minute data Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling

Dears, I have the following problem to solve: I have a Pandas Dataframe containing minutes data (df.minute) and a second Dataframe containing daily data (df.daily). The minute data is not homogeneous: for some days there might be more observations. The goal is to assign the data contained in df.daily to df.minute In other words for each day in df.daily take the data and assign it to all rows in df.minute where the date corresponds. I am pretty sure this can be done without using a loop. Many thanks

```
df.minute
time                   value
2016-07-30 17:00:00   102.00   
2016-07-30 17:01:00   102.12
2016-07-30 17:02:00   102.00
2016-07-30 17:03:00   102.99
2016-07-30 17:04:00   102.80
...
2016-07-31 11:40:00   100.45
2016-07-31 11:41:00   100.52
2016-07-31 11:42:00   100.55
2016-07-31 11:43:00   100.50
2016-07-31 11:44:00   100.00
...
2016-08-02 12:15:00   102.50
2016-08-02 12:16:00   102.54
2016-08-02 12:17:00   102.58
2016-08-02 12:18:00   102.65
2016-08-02 12:19:00   102.49
...

df.daily
time      value
2016-07-29  0.1
2016-07-30  0.2
2016-07-31  0.3
2016-08-01  0.4
2016-08-02  0.5
2016-08-03  0.6
2016-08-04  0.7
...
```

The result should be

```
df.minute
time                   value
2016-07-30 17:00:00    0.2   
2016-07-30 17:01:00    0.2 
2016-07-30 17:02:00    0.2 
2016-07-30 17:03:00    0.2 
2016-07-30 17:04:00    0.2 
...
2016-07-31 11:40:00    0.3
2016-07-31 11:41:00    0.3
2016-07-31 11:42:00    0.3
2016-07-31 11:43:00    0.3
2016-07-31 11:44:00    0.3
...
2016-08-02 12:15:00    0.5
2016-08-02 12:16:00    0.5
2016-08-02 12:17:00    0.5
2016-08-02 12:18:00    0.5
2016-08-02 12:19:00    0.5
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for remove times from `datetime`s:

```
df1['new'] = df1['time'].dt.floor('d').map(df2.set_index('time')['value'])
print (df1)
                  time   value  new
0  2016-07-30 17:00:00  102.00  0.2
1  2016-07-30 17:01:00  102.12  0.2
2  2016-07-30 17:02:00  102.00  0.2
3  2016-07-30 17:03:00  102.99  0.2
4  2016-07-30 17:04:00  102.80  0.2
5  2016-07-31 11:40:00  100.45  0.3
6  2016-07-31 11:41:00  100.52  0.3
7  2016-07-31 11:42:00  100.55  0.3
8  2016-07-31 11:43:00  100.50  0.3
9  2016-07-31 11:44:00  100.00  0.3
10 2016-08-02 12:15:00  102.50  0.5
11 2016-08-02 12:16:00  102.54  0.5
12 2016-08-02 12:17:00  102.58  0.5
13 2016-08-02 12:18:00  102.65  0.5
14 2016-08-02 12:19:00  102.49  0.5
```